# Zxing QR code scanner code is not working in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

I am trying to develop QR code scanner App using Zxing library in Kotlin. I am able to open the camera and scan the QR code but not getting response.

I also tried [this tutorial](https://tutorialwing.com/implement-android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxing-library-in-kotlin/) for implementation but did not get helped.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val mScanner = IntentIntegrator(activity)
        mScanner.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
        mScanner.setBeepEnabled(true)
        mScanner.initiateScan()

    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.contents == null) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Scanned: " + result.contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get response in a toast but when I tried to use debugger I am unable to go to onActivityResult() and the camera closes quickly.

Comment: can your share your logcat error details when camera closed & app crashed?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception in `result` @AsadChoudhary

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: `val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`

Comment: I added my answer. please check, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is not requesting the activity result. As you instantiate `IntentIntegrator(activity)` with the activity, it'll run `activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)`. Therefore you'll not receive the result within your fragment.

If you're still using `android.app.Fragment`, you only have to make sure to use your fragment to instantiate `IntentIntegrator(this@HomeFragment)`. Like this you'll get the result within your fragment, as it'll run `fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)` internally.

If you're using the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, you might need to copy the [sources for `IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) into your app and adapt the code to use the *AndroidX* fragment instead of the framework type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the scanner is sending info to your Activity's onActivityResult method, instead of to your fragment method. So the possible solution could be that in your fragment pass "this" as context instead of passing your activity as context. Like in your fragment

```
 val mScanner = IntentIntegrator(this); // pass fragment context
```

And in fragment wherever you are initializing the scanner pass Fragment as context instead of passing activity as context.

Comment: can you please update the code with latest dependency of zxing will help most.